# How to avoid extra space allocation when using standard collections and storing million items

Tags: c#, .net, performance, base-class-library

I'm using standard collections like List< T >, HashSet< T > and Dictionary< TKey, TValue > to store 100s thousand of items, up to million. Use case specific is that items set being huge in the beginning grows very slow and stays in memory for a long time. So the problem I'm facing (despite LOH allocation/fragmentation which is another issue) is that these collections consume a lot of memory due to their internal logic which doubles allocated memory every time it runs out of free space (actually it doubles and looks for nearest prime number). In my case, where adds are rare, keeping all that extra memory is wasteful.

Here is simplified version how I deal with List:

```
public static void Add_GrowSlow<T>([NotNull] this List<T> list, T item, int growStep)
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
    if (growStep <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(growStep));

    var count = list.Count;
    if (list.Capacity == count)
    {
        if (count > 10000)
        {
            list.Capacity = count + growStep;
        }
    }

    list.Add(item);
}
```

But I don't know how to deal with HashSet/Dictionary without reflection. Could you suggest any way or collection to avoid such problem? I looked at PowerCollections but found no solution for this problem.

**UPDATED:** I want to clarify what kind of answer I'd like to get: the name of nuget package or link to article with source code where collections, which allow to control how they grow, are implemented. Because obvious solution for my problem is to copy source code from BCL and make those **existing** methods protected virtual:

```
class HashSet<T>
{
    // ...
    protected virtual void IncreaseCapacity() {...}
}

class Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    // ...
    protected virtual void Resize() {...}
}
```

And I don't know why they didn't do this in BCL from the beginning. The cost of virtual call is nothing compared to reallocation and copying data which happens when collection resizes. May be I should create pull request?... :)

Comment: Have a look at this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191534/To-Heap-or-not-to-Heap-That-s-the-Large-Object-Que

Comment: I'd approach this from the other side: Do you *really* need all the items stay in memory? Or is it more like you only need a specific working set for a significant enough amount of time? Could it be a solution to store the item's data in a DB and do calculations / sorting / selection ... with SQL (or NoSQL for that matter)?

Comment: @Fildor the working set should stay in memory, because we're doing human-real-time calculations over it. And the problem is not with size of working set, but with collections as I mentioned.

Comment: @TomSchardt nice article but it's more about LOH and arrays. As I mentioned List causing less of the troubles and we don't facing LOH fragmentation issue, yet...

Comment: Is the size of the working set close to the size of the whole collection? Or is it significantly smaller? I am aiming to get rid of those vastly gigantic collections in the first place. My suspicion is you don't _really_ need them.

Comment: "because we're doing human-real-time calculations over it" - "Real-Time" is an empty shell until you define the constraints. I feel there is not enough info about the context in this question to give you useful advice :(

Comment: @Fildor I'm looking for collection where I can control how it grows, like I do with List. The problem domain is not related to the question and I don't see ways to reduce working set in memory. We need to fit into 100 milliseconds latency.

Comment: Is this an academic project or a tool used in one? If this is the case, I am sure there will be a cs-department at your uni that can assist with "big-data" handling in real-time constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153751/discussion-between-dmitry-naumov-and-fildor).

Comment: Use the `capacity` argument of the `List` and `Dictionary` constructors to reserve enough space in advance without doubling. Don't grow incrementally, just eat all of memory immediately. `HashSet` has no such feature; consider using a dictionary without values (or an advanced data structure like a Bloom filter, depending on what you're using it for). Growing is expensive whether or not the memory is doubled or not since stuff is inevitably copied over; consider dedicated structures like chunked lists if that's not good enough. You may have to write something yourself -- TANSTAAFL.